# Run function even when app minimized

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

I want to make function keep checking if the current date < or equals notification stored in local database, every 3 hours.

So I tried to do the following code to run function in background:

```
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        while(true){
            sleep(4)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print("hello  ")
            }
        }
    }
```

But this stops when the app go to the background, I mean when when you minimized the app, so I want to keep this function running even in minimized mode.

I need something similar to service in Android, I don't know if it exists.

Comment: You can use NSTimer to accomplish this functionality

Comment: Can you explain with code please

Comment: @E-housma Mardini : iOS does not allow any tasks to run in background forever. Your best bet is to use background modes like location update, expiration handler

Comment: You mean i should use location listener to do my function ?

Comment: @e-housma-mardini : Consider all the possible background modes and figure out what makes sense in your case and use it. There is no way for you to run a task in background like service in android. People often suggest using timer, local notifications or silent notifications and stuff like that. Timer will stop as soon as your app goes to background. local notifications that you schedule will not allow you to run code though you can add your code as actions but again needs user intervention finally silent notification isn't intended for this kind of things so completely in appropriate

Comment: oh thank you for it

Comment: @SandeepBhandari But how whatsapp can check if there is new msgs without stopping in this case

Comment: @E-housmaMardini, server can sent push notification when there's new messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that problem by using Alarms

```
var newAlarm:Alarms = Alarms(context:context)
```

Actually I followed this YouTube video to accomplish it

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yh3lLpV1k_Y

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 7.0, target: self, selector: #selector(moveToNextPage), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

Comment: it will stop after app go to background